# trying to get post meta value to return its value so I can then execute some code - keeps only showing first result

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, formidable

Trying to pull post_meta field (_custom_product_number_field) from a custom field set in woocommerce product listing.
The code executes but only shows the first result from where $week="1" in my formidable form. Does not show for any other "$weeks".
In short: Trying to get a week # from webpage, compare it to the value placed in the corresponding week # in formidable form (which has listing for each of 8 weeks), return the value to show on webpage how many spaces left.
I've checked to make sure that the correct meta value is being displayed on my form.
Appreciate any help where I am going wrong with this.

```
   add_shortcode( 'remainingweek', 'ff_simple_remaining_places7' );
  
 $week_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_product_number_field', true );

            function ff_simple_remaining_places7( $atts) {
                if ($week_id = "1") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 254,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 14 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id = "2") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 256,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 14 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id == "3") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 257,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id="4") { 
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 258,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id="5") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 259,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id="6") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 260,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
   
}
elseif ($week_id="7") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 262,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}
elseif ($week_id="8") {
            $places_taken     = FrmProStatisticsController::stats_shortcode( array(
            'id'   => 261,
            'type' => 'total'
            ) );//change 254 to the id of the field you want to count
    $remaining_places = 6 - $places_taken;//change to the total number of spaces at the event
 
    
}return $remaining_places;
            }
```

Comment: You managed to do exactly one of those comparisons right, in all the other places you are doing _assignments_ instead.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the "smack round the head :-)" moment. For some reason the get_post_meta value is not showing now for me to compare to - fun times.

Comment: That's because the variable `$week_id` does not exist inside your function. Why is that line placed _outside_ of it to begin with?